# Helly's number from biconvex functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, cg.comp-geom, convex-geometry

Helly's Theorem states the following. Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_N$ are convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, such that for any index-set $I$ with $|I| \leq h(d) := d+1$, we have $\bigcap_{i \in I} X_i \neq \varnothing$. Then $\bigcap_{i=1}^N X_i \neq \varnothing$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is convex, and for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is convex. Suppose $n \leq d$.

Define the sets 
$$ X_i := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid f( x, y_i ) \leq 0 \}, \ \forall i = 1, 2, ..., N,$$
where $y_1, ..., y_N \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are given vectors.

I am wondering if Helly's Theorem holds true with Helly's number $h$ depending on $n$, not on $d$.

Comment: Crossposted on Mathoverflow by "Frank" at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133184/hellys-number-from-biconvex-functions

Comment: It appears that you have crossposted this question *simultaneously*. While we don't mind a question being reposted, our [site policy](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/231/) prohibits simultaneous crossposting as it duplicates effort and fractures discussion. Crossposting is only permitted after sufficient time has passed and you have not obtained your desired answer elsewhere. When crossposting please summarize the relevant discussions from other sites in your question and link to the copies in both directions.

Comment: the MO question has a good answer, I think we should close this one

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414971/hellys-number-from-biconvex-functions